# Renault Megane I 1.6 Airconditioning pump seized

Tags: ac

My Renault Megane I 1.4 RT's airconditioning pump recently totally seized. When the seize happened, it also broke off the crank pulley. I have now replaced both the airconditioning pump and crank pulley, but the airconditioning pump is still not turning. I have also tested all relays on the relay board, checked all fuses on the fuse board and even reconnected the old aircon pump, which at this point is still able to be turned by the electrical system. Coincidentally, the old one will not turn when connected to the car. Anyone have an idea why the aircon pump is not getting power? Is there another relay/fuse I can check not located necessarily near the fuse/relay boards that I already checked? Any fuses/relays that are located in obscure places that anyone know of?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Was there any damage to the magnetic clutch? If the clutch was damaged, it could be the cause for the A/C compressor not working.